# Java MySQL | retrieving matches from many-to-many groupings

Tags: java, mysql, many-to-many

Considering three tables in MySQL:

```
product  
id - name - (more columns, irrelevant) ... 
13  - chair  
64  - table  

method  
id - name  
 1 - welding  
 2 - stamping  
10 - forging

product-method (many-to-many)  
product_id - method_id 
13 -  1  
13 -  2  
13 - 10  
64 -  1
```

Basically, what I need is a list of methods that are linked to a specific product.
In this example, I would like to get all methods that are used to make a chair (*product_id* 13 in **product-method**). The returned list should then be:

```
welding  
stamping  
forging
```

I began with this query:

```
SELECT method_id  
FROM `product-method`  
WHERE `product_id` = 13
```

which returns 1, 2 and 10

I tried this query to extract the **method**'s *names* from the returned *method_id*'s:

```
SELECT name  
FROM `product-method`  
WHERE id = (SELECT method_id FROM `product-method` WHERE product_id = 13)
```

which returns nothing.

What query should I use?

Comment: See about JOINs. And don't use '-' in a table/column identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name
FROM method
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT method_id FROM product_method WHERE product_id = 13
  )
```

it gets the applicable method_ids for given product_id from product_method table and then finds the name of the method from the method table using `IN` in the `WHERE` clause.

Alternatively, you can use JOIN like this:

```
Select m.*
From method m join product_method pm
On m.id = pm.method_id
Where pm.product_id = 13;
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility

```
 select m.name from method m, product_method pm
 where pm.product_id=13 and pm.method_id=m.id
```

In case you want only distinct values

```
 select distinct m.name from method m, product_method pm
 where pm.product_id=13 and pm.method_id=m.id
```

of course you can add to the fieldlist more fields from method, order them by id or name, etc..

Comment: We pretty much stopped writing queries this way back in 1992. Come join the 21st century